# How to make QT produce executable for Windows on Mac?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm writing my app on QT and I've produced a working version on my mac. How can make QT also compile an executable for windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt *SOURCE* is compatible to Windows, Mac, Linux, ARM and other platforms.

Qt *BINARIES* are platform-specific.  You cannot compile an .exe on the Mac, and hope to run that binary .exe on Windows or Linux.

You'll need to cross-compile, or actually install the Qt SDK and compile on each target platform, for each different kind of .exe.

Comment: thanks but I knew that I can't run .exe on mac. I just wanted to know if there is a way to compile a Windows distribution on OSX instead of moving the source to a pc machine to compile.

Comment: One way is to cross-compile (e.g. MinGW).  Personally, I'd just install the QT development kit for Windows on something like CrossOver, install MSVS express: http://www.microsoft.com/express, and compile QT from Visual Studio:  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/vs-add-in-1.1.7/index.html

Comment: In my experience, cross-compilation usually isn't worth the hassle and you'll need a Windows installation anyway to test if what you built actually works, so you don't gain that much. Additionally, if you're a good citizen writing unit tests, cross-compiling won't execute them on the target platform.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tutorial on cross compiling http://web.me.com/dove_family/martin/cross_compile.html

Or you can get a windows machine or virtual machine.  Build your app with a compiler on windows and link with the windows QT libraries.  For compilers you can use Visual Studio, or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)

Comment: Link is dead, this answer should be edited or removed.

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be [MinGW for OSX](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download). It should allow you to build Windows applications on OSX.

There are more detailed instructions in another question: [How do I configure Qt for cross-compilation from Linux to Windows target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934683/how-do-i-configure-qt-for-cross-compilation-from-linux-to-windows-target)