# How do I configure Qt for cross-compilation from Linux to Windows target?

Tags: linux, qt, mingw, cross-compiling

I want to cross compile the Qt libraries (and eventually my application) for a Windows x86_64 target using a Linux x86_64 host machine. I feel like I am close, but I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of some parts of this process.

I began by installing all the mingw packages on my Fedora machine and then modifying the `win32-g++` qmake.conf file to fit my environment. However, I seem to be getting stuck with some seemingly obvious configure options for Qt: `-platform` and `-xplatform`. Qt documentation says that `-platform` should be the host machine architecture (where you are compiling) and `-xplatform` should be the target platform for which you wish to deploy. In my case, I set `-platform linux-g++-64` and `-xplatform linux-win32-g++` where linux-win32-g++ is my modified win32-g++ configuration.

My problem is that, after executing configure with these options, I see that it invokes my system's compiler instead of the cross compiler (x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc). If I omit the `-xplatform` option and set `-platform` to my target spec (linux-win32-g++), it invokes the cross compiler but then errors when it finds some Unix related functions aren't defined.

Here is some output from my latest attempt: http://pastebin.com/QCpKSNev.

Questions:

1. When cross-compiling something like Qt for Windows from a Linux host, should the native compiler *ever* be invoked? That is, during a cross compilation process, shouldn't we use *only* the cross compiler? I don't see why Qt's configure script tries to invoke my system's native compiler when I specify the `-xplatform` option.
2. If I'm using a mingw cross-compiler, when will I have to deal with a specs file? Spec files for GCC are still sort of a mystery to me, so I am wondering if some background here will help me.
3. In general, beyond specifying a cross compiler in my qmake.conf, what else might I need to consider?

Comment: I believe it needs a local build of qmake to bootstrap the rest of the build. see also links in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025687/cross-compile-in-linux-or-windows

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I now just found another problem, I seem to be mixing native and cross toolchains. The error in my pastebin output seems to be due to calling `x86_64-w64-mingw32-as` instead of the native one.

Comment: I rarely mark an SO question as a favorite but this was a unique and interesting question with a cool answer.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Just use [M cross environment (MXE)](http://mxe.cc/). It takes the pain out of the whole process:

- Get it:

  ```
  $ git clone https://github.com/mxe/mxe.git
  ```
- Install [build dependencies](http://mxe.cc/#requirements)
- Build Qt for Windows, its dependencies, and the cross-build tools;
  this will take about an hour on a fast machine with decent internet access;
  the download is about 500MB:

  ```
  $ cd mxe && make qt
  ```
- Go to the directory of your app and add the cross-build tools to the **PATH** environment variable:

  ```
  $ export PATH=<mxe root>/usr/bin:$PATH
  ```
- Run the Qt Makefile generator tool then build:

  ```
  $ <mxe root>/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/qt/bin/qmake && make
  ```
- You should find the binary in the ./release directory:

  ```
  $ wine release/foo.exe
  ```

**Some notes**:

- Use the master branch of the MXE repository; it appears to get a lot more love from the development team.
- The output is a 32-bit static binary, which will work well on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: **note**: these instructions apply to Qt 4; for Qt 5, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14170591

Comment: Before executing `$ cd mxe && make qt` you should install the requirements. For Debian systems this means `sudo apt-get install  autoconf automake autopoint bash bison bzip2 cmake flex gettext git g++ gperf intltool libffi-dev libtool libltdl-dev libssl-dev libxml-parser-perl make openssl patch perl pkg-config python ruby scons sed unzip wget xz-utils`. For other systems, see http://mxe.cc/#requirements

Comment: it is 2023, and these are still working instructions, except compiling "qt" failed for me and I had to use "qt5" instead on WSL Ubuntu 22.04, `cd mxe && make qt5`.

Answer (score 19):

(This is an update of @Tshepang's answer, as MXE has evolved since his answer)

## Building Qt

Rather than using `make qt` to build Qt, you can use `MXE_TARGETS` to control your target machine and toolchain (32- or 64-bit). MXE started using `.static` and `.shared` as a part of the target name to show which type of lib you want to build.

```
# The following is the same as `make qt`, see explanation on default settings after the code block.
make qt MXE_TARGETS=i686-w64-mingw32.static   # MinGW-w64, 32-bit, static libs

# Other targets you can use:
make qt MXE_TARGETS=x86_64-w64-mingw32.static # MinGW-w64, 64-bit, static libs
make qt MXE_TARGETS=i686-w64-mingw32.shared   # MinGW-w64, 32-bit, shared libs

# You can even specify two targets, and they are built in one run:
# (And that's why it is MXE_TARGET**S**, not MXE_TARGET ;)
# MinGW-w64, both 32- and 64-bit, static libs
make qt MXE_TARGETS='i686-w64-mingw32.static x86_64-w64-mingw32.static'
```

In @Tshepang's original answer, he did not specify an `MXE_TARGETS`, and the default is used. At the time he wrote his answer, the default was `i686-pc-mingw32`, now it's `i686-w64-mingw32.static`. If you explicitly set `MXE_TARGETS` to `i686-w64-mingw32`, omitting `.static`, a warning is printed because this syntax is now deprecated. If you try to set the target to `i686-pc-mingw32`, it will show an error as MXE has removed support for MinGW.org (i.e. i686-pc-mingw32).

## Running `qmake`

As we changed the `MXE_TARGETS`, the `<mxe root>/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/qt/bin/qmake` command will no longer work. Now, what you need to do is:

```
<mxe root>/usr/<TARGET>/qt/bin/qmake
```

If you didn't specify `MXE_TARGETS`, do this:

```
<mxe root>/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt/bin/qmake
```

**Update:** The new default is now `i686-w64-mingw32.static`

Comment: Thanks much for the update. It's also good to have someone working directly on the project respond.

Comment: This should have been an edit/update to the other answer, not a new one.

Comment: @Hugo The edit page says:
How to edit:
► fix grammatical or spelling errors
► clarify meaning without changing it
► correct minor mistakes
► add related resources or links
► always respect the original author

This is not any of those. It is an extension of Tshepang's answer.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, when I type "make qt...." it just responds with 'no rule to make target qt'.

Answer (score 9):

Another way to cross-compile software for Windows on Linux is the MinGW-w64 toolchain on Archlinux. It is easy to use and maintain, and it provides recent versions of the compiler and many libraries. I personally find it easier than MXE and it seems to adopt newer versions of libraries faster.

First, you will need an arch-based machine (virtual machine or docker container will suffice). It does not have to be Arch Linux, derivatives will do as well. I used Manjaro Linux.
Most of the MinGW-w64 packages are not available at the official Arch repositories, but there is [plenty in AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&SeB=nd&K=mingw-w64&outdated=&SB=p&SO=d&PP=250&do_Search=Go). The default package manager for Arch (Pacman) does not support installation directly from AUR, so you will need to install and use an AUR wrapper like yay or yaourt. Then installing MinGW-w64 version of Qt5 and Boost libraries is as easy as:

```
yay -Sy mingw-w64-qt5-base mingw-w64-boost
#yaourt -Sy mingw-w64-qt5-base mingw-w64-qt5-boost #if you use yaourt
```

This will also install the MinGW-w64 toolchain (`mingw-w64-gcc`) and other dependencies.
Cross-compiling a Qt project for windows (x64) is then as simple as:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-qmake-qt5
make
```

To deploy your program you will need to copy [corresponding dlls](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) from `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/`. For example, you will typically need to copy `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll` to  `program.exe_dir/platforms/qwindows.dll`.

To get a 32bit version you simply need to use `i686-w64-mingw32-qmake-qt5` instead. Cmake-based projects work just as easily with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-cmake`.
This approach worked extremely well for me, was the easiest to set-up, maintain, and extend.
It also goes well with continuous integration services. There are [docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/burningdaylight/mingw-arch) available too.

For example, let's say I want to build QNapi subtitle downloader GUI. I could do it in two steps:

1. Start the docker container:

```
sudo docker run -it burningdaylight/mingw-arch:qt /bin/bash
```

2. Clone and compile QNapi

```
git clone --recursive 'https://github.com/QNapi/qnapi.git' 
cd qnapi/ 
x86_64-w64-mingw32-qmake-qt5
make
```

That's it! In many cases, it will be that easy. Adding your own libraries to the package repository (AUR) is also straightforward. You would need to [write a PKBUILD file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/creating_packages), which is as intuitive as it can get, see [mingw-w64-rapidjson](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=mingw-w64-rapidjson), for example.

Comment: For deployment, you have to copy all required Qt DLLs (or http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html). Make sure /mingw64/share/qt5/plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll to be copied into platforms/qwindows.dll.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I think I've got it figured out.

Based in part on https://github.com/mxe/mxe/blob/master/src/qt.mk and https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/contrib/src/qt4/rules.mak

It appears that "initially" when you run configure (with -xtarget, etc.), it configures then runs your "hosts" gcc to build the local binary file ./bin/qmake

```
 ./configure -xplatform win32-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=$cross_prefix_here -nomake examples ...
```

then you run normal "make" and it builds it for mingw

```
  make
  make install
```

so

1. yes
2. only if you need to use something other than msvcrt.dll (its default).  Though I have never used anything else so I don't know for certain.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18792925/32453 lists some configure params.

Answer (score 4):

In order to compile Qt, one must run it's `configure` script, specifying the host platform with `-platform`  (e.g. `-platform linux-g++-64` if you're building on a 64-bit linux with the g++ compiler) and the target platform with `-xplatform` (e.g. `-xplatform win32-g++` if you're cross compiling to windows).

I've also added this flag:
`-device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-`
which specifies the prefix of the toolchain I'm using, which will get prepended to 'gcc' or 'g++' in all the makefiles that are building binaries for windows.

Finally, you might get problems while building [idc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/activeqt-idc.html), which apparently is something that is used to add ActiveX support to Qt. You can avoid that by passing the flag `-skip qtactiveqt` to the configure script. I've got this one out of this bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38223

Here's the whole configure command I've used:

```
    cd qt_source_directory
    mkdir my_build
    cd my_build
    ../configure \
      -release \
      -opensource \
      -no-compile-examples \
      -platform linux-g++-64 \
      -xplatform win32-g++ \
      -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32- \
      -skip qtactiveqt \
      -v
```

As for yout questions:

1 - Yes. The native compiler will be called in order to build some tools that are needed in the build process. Maybe things like qconfig or qmake, but I'm not entirely sure which tools, exactly.

2 - Sorry. I have no idea what specs files are in the context of compilers =/ . But as far as I know, you wouldn't have to deal with that.

3 - You can specify the cross compiler prefix in the configure command line instead of doing it in the qmake.conf file, as mentioned above. And there's also that problem with idc, whose workaround I've mentioned as well.