# qt5.4 crosscompile on linux for windows

Tags: c++, linux, git, qt, cross-compiling

Folks, I've got problems following this [Building Qt 5 on Linux, for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170590/building-qt-5-on-linux-for-windows/14170591#14170591) and the dozen of other answers here or on other sites didn't help that much.

As suggested by the answer there, I did this:
-installed git, not from the link there though, it didn't work.
-installed build dependencies

Now I'm stuck at the third part where it says "Build QT 5 for Windows: ". What does this actually mean? I don't know how to go about it!  I tried running that command there ("cd mxe && make qtbase") but there was just an warning (error) ...no such file or directory.

From searching around I kinda figured that I need to "rebuild" (?) qt5 somehow but I'm not sure what this means or how it can be done.

My first time asking here. From what I read on the rules of this site (someone should write a book about those) this question will be closed as dupplicate but on the other hand bringing old questions back to live is discouraged too so I didn't know what to do. Anyway if this does violate any of those rules that I didn't have the time to read feel free to remove/delete it or just a comment and I'll do it myself.

My system. An old PC, lubuntu x32 installed, 2 gb of ram.

Comment: Did you run `git clone https://github.com/mxe/mxe.git`? This downloads the sources of MXE from GitHub. Then `cd mxe && make qtbase` should work as well.

Comment: I uninstalled Linux for the time being and installed windows 7. I felt that this task (crosscompiling) was way over my head. Thank You for your time though.

Answer (score 0):

you should write full path to the mxe directory, like

```
cd /home/username/path/to/qt/mxe
```

that's somewhere under the path that you used to clone repository into

Comment: I can't find anything that even resembles mxe under the qt directory. I'm very, very new to linux, just started using it a couple of days ago so forgive my ignorance. Thanks for the answer.