# mxe cross compiler QSerialPort on mac

Tags: macos, cross-platform, qt5, qtserialport, mxe

I am using qt 5.5.1 on mac os x and would like to develop an application for windows. So far so good. I have installed the cross compiler [M cross environment (MXE)](http://mxe.cc/) to generate .exe files. The compiler seems to work but I have the problem that mxe does not know the Qt library serialport. Because of using qt5.5 I no longer need to build Qt Serial Port manually. Qt Serial Port is officially part of Qt AFAIK. If I run the Qt Makefile generator tool with command:

```
<mxe root>/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5
```

I get the following error message:

```
Unknown module(s) in QT: serialport
```

In my applications *.pro file I added the following line:

```
QT       += serialport
```

Can anyone help me at this point. I think I have to link the serialport lib with mxe. But do not know how to solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When building the qt packages of mxe, you should also build the qtserialport package. For Linux, [refer to these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170590/building-qt-5-on-linux-for-windows/14170591#14170591). Instead of

```
cd mxe && make qtbase
```

Do this:

```
cd mxe && make qtbase qtserialport
```