# Building my Qt5.5 app using mxe with Qt3D support

Tags: linux, windows, qt5, qt3d, mxe

Basically I am following [these instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170590/building-qt-5-on-linux-for-windows/14170591#14170591) on how to successfully cross compile my `Qt5.5` project on *Ubuntu* for *Microsoft Windows*.

My project has dependency on `Qt3D`, which I was hoping would be supported by `mxe`, however, when I invoke the build of my project with an `mxe` prepared with Qt5 it reports promptly that:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: 3dcore 3drenderer 3dinput
```

Furthermore, if I build "qt3d" target for mxe it waits a few seconds before reporting the following:

```
me@box:~/Desktop/Projects/Project/mxe$ make qt3d
[using autodetected 6 job(s)]
me@box:~/Desktop/Projects/Project/mxe$
```

In other words a big lazy nothing seems to happen.

So in terms suitable for a complete mxe beginner like myself, what would be the correct way to invoke make for mxe to have it build qt5 with Qt3D support so that I can cross compile my project with the resulting mxe qmake?

Thanks!