# How to deploy cross-platform applications with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, cross-platform

I have been coding in Qt for few years using MSVC and QtCreator on Windows.

Now I have decided to move to Linux environment and continue my development under Ubuntu. I then wish to compile the result on Windows machine for Windows executable, I expect no issues as the Qt code will be platform independent.

So I have all my .cpp, .ui, .h, .pro and other files on Ubuntu, I can compile it from Qt Creator or using command line, and now I wish to deploy for Windows too. How do I proceed? Do I copy all files on Windows machine every time and open project in QtCreator on Windows? Or can I automate this process somehow to be able to use e.g. a network-shared folder and avoid Windows Qt Creator modifying my code developed under Linux Qt Creator? There is lack of documentation when it comes to cross-platform deployment, yet this is the key feature advertised by Qt everywhere.

Is some code editing needed? What is the best approach in this scenario?

Comment: "...a network-shared folder" No, synchronizing your code between computers is what version control systems are for.

Comment: so I should simply use git and get the latest version in Win and then compile? Is that all it takes (+ of course add dependecies libs)?

Comment: "so I should simply use git and get the latest version in Win and then compile?" .. yes !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using version control e.g. [git](https://git-scm.com/) you commit on Linux env and then checkout and build manually on Windows.

And by setting up continuous integration on Windows e.g. [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/index.html), [Buildbot](http://buildbot.net/) you can automate build process so that when you commit to version control on Linux the CI builds automatically on Windows.

Or you can [use MXE to cross-compile on Linux for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170590/building-qt-5-on-linux-for-windows/14170591#14170591).