# QT how to cross compile for Windows on linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gcc, cross-platform

Good day all

I need to test and distibute software I have written for Linux, to Windows.

I am using Qt Creator 4.0.2 (based on QT 5.7.0).

I have found a tutorial regarding this, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170590/building-qt-5-on-linux-for-windows/14170591#14170591), but had an issue building the compilter.

*Unfortunately while building the compilter (MinGW32), I have run into an error - VTK package cannot be built - and have not found a solution since.*

for the record:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005
```

**Is there any other methods avaiable to build cross-platform applications in Linux using QT-Creator?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Install Windows in a virtual machine... VirtualBox shoul be good enough. From my experiance, a lot easier than trying to cross compile...

Comment: should I import my .pro file and carry on asif in linux? why not attempt cross-compiling?

Comment: Yes, install Qt and Qt Creator in windows, copy your code over and open as if in Linux and compile. You can attempt it if you have a good guide and understanding of what you need to do, but it can become tricky and complicated rather fast, if your hardware allows it or you have a spare computer, setting up windows might be easier