# Trying to cross-compile qt4/qt5 applications from Linux Ubuntu 32bit to Windows (32bit)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, makefile, cross-compiling

I tried to cross-compile the following code:

```
//test.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;
    window.resize(250, 150);
    window.setWindowTitle("Test");
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

following those instructions: [Building Qt 5 on Linux, for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170590/building-qt-5-on-linux-for-windows?answertab=votes#tab-top). I downloaded and built the source, created a Makefile and tried to build my project. after getting lot of `undefined reference` errors, I changed the includes to

```
#include "/home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtWidgets/QApplication"
#include "/home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtWidgets/QWidget"
```

and changed some paths in the Makefiles. But I am still getting lots of errors:

```
make
make -f Makefile.Release
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/administrator/louis/buildwin »
/home/administrator/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -std=gnu++11 -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I. -I. -I../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include -I../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtGui -I../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtCore -Irelease -I../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o release/test.o test.cpp
/home/administrator/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o release/buildwin.exe release/test.o release/buildwin_plugin_import.o  -lglu32 -lmingw32 -L/home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libqtmain.a -L/home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib -L/home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib -L/home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins/platforms /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwindows.a -lwinspool /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5PlatformSupport.a /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5DBus.a -ldbus-1 -liphlpapi -ldbghelp -lnetapi32 -L/home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins/imageformats /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqico.a /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Gui.a -lcomdlg32 -loleaut32 -limm32 -lopengl32 -ljpeg -lharfbuzz -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lfontconfig -lusp10 -lmsimg32 -lgdi32 -lpixman-1 -lffi -lexpat -lfreetype -lbz2 -lharfbuzz_too -lglib-2.0 -lwinmm -lshlwapi -lpcre -lintl -liconv -lpng16 /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.a -lole32 -luuid -lws2_32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmpr -lz -lpcre16 
release/test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)'
release/test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `QWidget::QWidget(QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)'
release/test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `QWidget::resize(QSize const&)'
release/test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xc8): undefined reference to `QWidget::setWindowTitle(QString const&)'
release/test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `QWidget::show()'
release/test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xf3): undefined reference to `QApplication::exec()'
release/test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to `QWidget::~QWidget()'
release/test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication()'
release/test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `QWidget::~QWidget()'
release/test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.Release:62 : la recette pour la cible « release/buildwin.exe » a échouée
make[1]: *** [release/buildwin.exe] Erreur 1
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/administrator/louis/buildwin »
Makefile:34 : la recette pour la cible « release » a échouée
make: *** [release] Erreur 2
```

Those are the Makefiles. I only modified a few paths

in Makefile:

```
# Makefile for building: buildwin
# Generated by qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.7.1)
# Project:  buildwin.pro
# Template: app
# Command: /home/administrator/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5 -o Makefile buildwin.pro

MAKEFILE      = Makefile
first: release
install: release-install
uninstall: release-uninstall
QMAKE         = /home/administrator/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
COPY          = cp -f
COPY_FILE     = cp -f
COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
INSTALL_DIR   = cp -f -R
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
SUBTARGETS    =  \
        release \
        debug
release: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release
release-make_first: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release 
release-all: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release all
release-clean: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release clean
release-distclean: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release distclean
release-install: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release install
release-uninstall: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release uninstall
debug: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug
debug-make_first: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug 
debug-all: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug all
debug-clean: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug clean
debug-distclean: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug distclean
debug-install: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug install
debug-uninstall: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug uninstall

Makefile: buildwin.pro ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/win32-g++/qmake.conf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/qdevice.pri \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/device_config.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/common/angle.conf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bootstrap_private.pri \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent.pri \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent_private.pri \
        ###I shortened here to fit the 30k limit...
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qwindows.pri \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_windowsprintersupport.pri \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/qt_config.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/win32-g++/qmake.conf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/default_pre.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds_post.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/rtti.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/precompile_header.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/resources.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/moc.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/opengl.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/file_copies.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/windows.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/exceptions.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        buildwin.pro \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/qtmain.prl \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/Qt5Gui.prl \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/Qt5Core.prl \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins/platforms/qwindows.prl \
        ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins/imageformats/qico.prl
    $(QMAKE) -o Makefile buildwin.pro
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/qdevice.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/device_config.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/common/angle.conf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/qconfig.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bootstrap_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_platformsupport_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_zlib_private.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qgenericbearer.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qico.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qminimal.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qnativewifibearer.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qsqlite.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qsqlmysql.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qsqlodbc.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qsqlpsql.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qsqltds.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtuiotouchplugin.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qwindows.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_windowsprintersupport.pri:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/qt_config.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/win32-g++/qmake.conf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/default_pre.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds_post.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/rtti.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/precompile_header.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/resources.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/moc.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/opengl.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/file_copies.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/windows.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/exceptions.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/lex.prf:
buildwin.pro:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/qtmain.prl:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/Qt5Gui.prl:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/Qt5Core.prl:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins/platforms/qwindows.prl:
../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins/imageformats/qico.prl:
qmake: FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -o Makefile buildwin.pro

qmake_all: FORCE

make_first: release-make_first debug-make_first  FORCE
all: release-all debug-all  FORCE
clean: release-clean debug-clean  FORCE
distclean: release-distclean debug-distclean  FORCE
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile
    -$(DEL_FILE) /home/administrator/louis/buildwin/buildwin_plugin_import.cpp

release-mocclean:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release mocclean
debug-mocclean:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug mocclean
mocclean: release-mocclean debug-mocclean

release-mocables:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Release mocables
debug-mocables:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).Debug mocables
mocables: release-mocables debug-mocables

check: first

benchmark: first
FORCE:

$(MAKEFILE).Release: Makefile
$(MAKEFILE).Debug: Makefile
```

in Makefile.Release:

```
# Makefile for building: buildwin
# Generated by qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.7.1)
# Project:  buildwin.pro
# Template: app

MAKEFILE      = Makefile.Release
## Compiler, tools and options

CC            = /home/administrator/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-gcc
CXX           = /home/administrator/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++
DEFINES       = -DUNICODE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN
CFLAGS        = -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -Wall -Wextra $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -std=gnu++11 -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I. -I. -I../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include -I../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtGui -I../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtCore -Irelease -I../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/win32-g++ 
LINKER      =        /home/administrator/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++
LFLAGS        =        -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads
LIBS        =        -lglu32 -lmingw32 -L/home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libqtmain.a -L/home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib -L/home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib -L/home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins/platforms /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwindows.a -lwinspool /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5PlatformSupport.a /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5DBus.a -ldbus-1 -liphlpapi -ldbghelp -lnetapi32 -L/home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins/imageformats /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqico.a /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Gui.a -lcomdlg32 -loleaut32 -limm32 -lopengl32 -ljpeg -lharfbuzz -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lfontconfig -lusp10 -lmsimg32 -lgdi32 -lpixman-1 -lffi -lexpat -lfreetype -lbz2 -lharfbuzz_too -lglib-2.0 -lwinmm -lshlwapi -lpcre -lintl -liconv -lpng16 /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.a -lole32 -luuid -lws2_32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmpr -lz -lpcre16 
QMAKE         = /home/administrator/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5
IDC           = idc
IDL           = midl
ZIP           = 
DEF_FILE      = 
RES_FILE      = 
COPY          = cp -f
SED           = sed
COPY_FILE     = cp -f
COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
INSTALL_FILE    = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
INSTALL_DIR     = cp -f -R

### Output directory
OBJECTS_DIR   = release/
### Files

SOURCES       = test.cpp /home/administrator/louis/buildwin/buildwin_plugin_import.cpp
OBJECTS       = release/test.o \
        release/buildwin_plugin_import.o

DIST          =   test.cpp
QMAKE_TARGET  = buildwin
DESTDIR        = release/ #avoid trailing-slash linebreak
TARGET         = buildwin.exe
DESTDIR_TARGET = release/buildwin.exe

## Build rules
first: all
all: Makefile.Release  $(DESTDIR_TARGET)
$(DESTDIR_TARGET): /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Gui.a /home/administrator/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.a $(OBJECTS) 
    $(LINKER) $(LFLAGS) -o $(DESTDIR_TARGET) $(OBJECTS)  $(LIBS)
qmake: FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -o Makefile.Release buildwin.pro
qmake_all: FORCE
dist:
    $(ZIP) buildwin.zip $(SOURCES) $(DIST) buildwin.pro ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/qdevice.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/device_config.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/common/angle.conf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/qconfig.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bootstrap_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_platformsupport_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_zlib_private.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qgenericbearer.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qico.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qminimal.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qnativewifibearer.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qsqlite.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qsqlmysql.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qsqlodbc.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qsqlpsql.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qsqltds.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtuiotouchplugin.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qwindows.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_windowsprintersupport.pri ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/qt_config.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/win32-g++/qmake.conf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/default_pre.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds_post.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/build_pass.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/rtti.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/precompile_header.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/resources.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/moc.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/opengl.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/file_copies.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/win32/windows.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/exceptions.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/features/lex.prf buildwin.pro ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/qtmain.prl ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/Qt5Gui.prl ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/Qt5Core.prl ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins/platforms/qwindows.prl ../../mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins/imageformats/qico.prl  NO_PCH_SOURCES RESOURCES HEADERS SOURCES OBJECTIVE_SOURCES YACCSOURCES YACCSOURCES LEXSOURCES 

clean: compiler_clean 
    -$(DEL_FILE) release/test.o release/buildwin_plugin_import.o
distclean: clean 
    -$(DEL_FILE) /home/administrator/louis/buildwin/buildwin_plugin_import.cpp
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(DESTDIR_TARGET)
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile.Release
mocclean: compiler_moc_header_clean compiler_moc_source_clean
mocables: compiler_moc_header_make_all compiler_moc_source_make_all
check: first
benchmark: first
compiler_no_pch_compiler_make_all:
compiler_no_pch_compiler_clean:
compiler_rcc_make_all:
compiler_rcc_clean:
compiler_moc_header_make_all:
compiler_moc_header_clean:
compiler_moc_source_make_all:
compiler_moc_source_clean:
compiler_yacc_decl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_decl_clean:
compiler_yacc_impl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_impl_clean:
compiler_lex_make_all:
compiler_lex_clean:
compiler_clean: 
####### Compile

release/test.o: test.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o release/test.o test.cpp

release/buildwin_plugin_import.o: /home/administrator/louis/buildwin/buildwin_plugin_import.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o release/buildwin_plugin_import.o /home/administrator/louis/buildwin/buildwin_plugin_import.cpp

####### Install

install:  FORCE

uninstall:  FORCE

FORCE:
```

Probably it is just a simple include mistake, or a wrong line in the makefiles

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: It looks like you didn't run QMake to regenerate the Makefile for your new platform.

Comment: Why not just set up a virtual machine with Windows and compile natively?  So much less pain that way..

Comment: try with: ln -s {mxe root}/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ar /usr/bin
ln -s {mxe root}/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5 /usr/bin
ln -s {mxe root}/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++  /usr/bin  
ln -s {mxe root}/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-windres /usr/bin
ln -s {mxe root}/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-gcc /usr/bin