# Build QT5 project on Ubuntu for Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt

I tried to build qt project on Ubuntu for windows, following the steps in this post
[Building Qt 5 on Linux, for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170590/building-qt-5-on-linux-for-windows/14170591#14170591)

Everything is good except when I run make command, it complains about "i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++: Command not found". But I did see i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ under /root/mxe/usr/bin. I have no idea what happen. Do I miss something?

Answer (score -1):

You can try run the command directly in shell. If it goes wrong again, check the PATH.