# Qt5 cross-compilation using MXE and NetworkAuth

Tags: qt, ubuntu, networking, cross-compiling

I am trying to do a Qt cross-compilation from Linux(Ubuntu 16.04) to Windows by following these steps: [Building Qt 5 on Linux, for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170590/building-qt-5-on-linux-for-windows/14170591#14170591).

I successfully installed the full Qt5 using MXE and the above mentioned steps but, unhappily, I get an error regarding the NetworkAuth library, right after running

> i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5

in my project folder:

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: networkauth

My .pro project file contains the networkauth inclusion as per [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetworkauth-index.html) and is successfully compiled under Qt Creator:

```
QT = gui core multimedia network networkauth
```

I looked into < mxe root >/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib and could only find libQt5Network.a and libQt5Network.prl, but no networkAuth related files.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `networkauth` package was missing from MXE. I've created one and there's a pull request for it now: https://github.com/mxe/mxe/pull/2112

You can either wait until it's been accepted into the main project or [build the patch](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/) or [our fork](https://github.com/MarginUG/mxe) manually.