# How to compile a Qt program without installing sdk

Tags: c++, windows, qt, compilation

Can someone tell me if it's possible to compile a project that works with Qt but without installing the entire sdk ? I mean, something like recompile Qt source code and link the libraries or something like this.

I know my problem is weird but I work in special conditions : I am on a linux machine and I have to work on a windows project therefore I use a distant server on windows to compile but I can't install anything on this serveur. I need an idea to have a fully portable folder with Qt who can compile without installing anything.

I hope I was clear in my explications.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should install compiler (e.g minGW) and Qt library (any version), set into 'PATH' path to `qmake`, start windows terminal (cmd or powershell or etc), move to directory with your source code of Qt Project and run `qmake`, then you should be exec `make` (e.g. for windows you can install minGW compiler (`mingw32-make`))

Comment: When you say "set into PATH", what do you exactly mean?

Comment: Excuse me, for your case, you should choosen 2 way. Build static Qt Library from source code and use static linking with your project. Or, install Qt library and to copy them near your project

Comment: I guess here you can find your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934683/how-do-i-configure-qt-for-cross-compilation-from-linux-to-windows-target

Comment: @Amartel, it's a good post but I don't need to compile on Linux to Windows, I need to know how compile Qt without installing anything on Windows. But thank you too for your help, this may be usefull later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I has combined comments in answer.

1. You need to install compiler (e.g minGW) and Qt Library (as needed version).
2. You should add into environment variable 'PATH' your path to `qmake` and compiler.
3. Start terminal and move to directory with your source code of Qt project.
4. Run `qmake` and then exec `make` (e.g. It, for minGW, is `mingw32-make`).

For your case, you may choosen 2 way:

1. Build static Qt Library from source code and use static linking with your project.
2. Install Qt Library and copy libraries near your project with dynamic linking (recomended).