# How to tell make to use mingw32 instead of gcc

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling, wkhtmltopdf, mingw32

I'm trying to build wkhtmltopdf for Windows on an Ubuntu box. I haven't done much with cross-compiling in the past, but I have installed the Mingw32 compiler and am having trouble figuring out how to build qt to target Windows instead of Linux. Right now I am not sure how to tell ./configure to use Mingw32 to build a windows version of Qt when I run make. Can anybody shed some light on how to do this?

I have tried building wkhtmltopdf on Windows in the past, but got stuck at the step where you need to run qmake after building Qt, which is why I am trying to build on a native linux environment instead.

Comment: [How do I configure Qt for cross-compilation from Linux to Windows target?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934683/how-do-i-configure-qt-for-cross-compilation-from-linux-to-windows-target?rq=1), [Building Qt Desktop for Windows with MinGW](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MinGW)

Comment: When I follow the second link (building natively on Windows), I get an error when running configure.exe... "project.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized"

Comment: You don't need to build `Qt` library frome source. [Qt official website](http://qt-project.org/downloads) provide pre-build binary installer for common desktop configurations.

Comment: According the wkhtmltopdf documentation, it requires a specially patched version of Qt for the functionality I need built into it (e.g. internal links). Since I don't know enough to patch the source myself, I have to use the patched source provided by Antialize. I ended up figuring out how to build the source but I keep running into other issues building natively on Windows. I'm going to try the cross compiling route with mxe as explained in the first link you provided.