# How to recompile in MXE only a specific package?

Tags: c++, qt4, cross-compiling, mxe

I've used [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13211922/2429611) as a recipie to build Qt GUI applications for Windows on Linux. It works perfectly. But my resulting "Hello World" binary is 12MB big - only for a button in a window - and this is too much.

So I thought I could modify the `src/qt.mk` file and adjust the configure options to remove as many unneeded options as possible.

But now I need to recompile Qt inside MXE and I don't know how. When I run `make` in the base directory it begins to download all source packages. But I've already downloaded this stuff.

So how to only recompile the qt part so that my changes will take effect?

Comment: You could try deleting usr/<target>/qt and usr/<target>/qt5, then running `make qt` again.

Answer (score 1):

```
touch src/<packagename>.mk
make <packagename>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the base directory of `mxe` simply open the file `settings.mk` and uncomment the last three lines:

```
LOCAL_PKG_LIST := <packages-to-recompile-here>
.DEFAULT local-pkg-list:
local-pkg-list: $(LOCAL_PKG_LIST)
```

If you place at `<packages-to-recompile-here>` your packages which should be recompiled and then run `make` in the base directory of `mxe` it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply running **make $packagename** will rebuild *$packagename* in your mxe checkout if something was changed on *src/$packagename.mk*