# How to cross compile Qt application from one OS (linux) to the others (Windows & MAC)?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, qt, cross-platform

As the title says, I wrote on my linux machine a small application, which should be able to run on Windows and MAC as well.

Since the application is pure Qt, I was hoping that I just need to install additional Qt compilers for Windows and MAC? Without running any VMs or additional Windows/MAC operating systems.

Comment: Why without a VM? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285935/building-an-app-on-linux-for-windows/30289410#30289410

Answer (score 0):

For the Windows targets, you can use the [M cross environment](http://mxe.cc).

I have tested it on ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 15.04, working like a charm for building static Qt4 or Qt5 executables.