# How Do I Configure Qmake for Cross Compilation?

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, qmake

What I have done so far is create two makefiles: a project makefile and a package makefile.The project makefile was,however, created using qmake. When I compile the package, I get an x86-64 binary which means the makefile is not cross compiling. How can I fix this?

Here's a the part where I believe the source of the problem:

```
CC            = gcc
CXX           = g++
DEFINES       = -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED
CFLAGS        = -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4 -I.
LINK          = g++
LFLAGS        = -m64 -Wl,-O1
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcrypto -lssl -lQtCore -lpthread 
AR            = ar cqs
RANLIB        = 
QMAKE         = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
COPY          = cp -f
SED           = sed
COPY_FILE     = $(COPY)
COPY_DIR      = $(COPY) -r
STRIP         = strip
INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
```

I changed the first line "CC = gcc" to "CC ?=gcc" but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934683/how-do-i-configure-qt-for-cross-compilation-from-linux-to-windows-target

Comment: You need to re-generate the qmake generated makefile using the correct qmake mkspec for your target.  For instance, to cross-compile a Qt application for QNX on x86, I can use `qmake -spec qnx-x86-qcc` to generate the appropriate makefile.