# Qt Windows + Linux Cross-compiling

Tags: linux, windows, qt, cross-platform

I have developed Qt on Windows for Windows, and on Linux for Linux.

I understand that in order to develop a Qt application for both Windows + Linux is well documented (although I haven't actually done it yet).

What I would like to do is create a Qt project but run it on both Windows + Linux .

Is this possible?

Comment: "I have developed Qt on Windows for Windows, and on Linux for Linux." What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I don't get your distinctions or what the exact problem is. If your code is portable (if you stick to Qt, it usually is), you can develop on Windows and compile and run it on Linux afterwards, or vice-versa.

Comment: Sure it is possible to develop on several platforms, this is target of Qt

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming you're asking about developing Qt Project on both Operating system.**
Yes . you can open your project in both operating system if you have Qt Creator or related development application installed.

**Assuming you want to compile your project for both Operating systems**
you can follow up this for cross-compilation : [How do I configure Qt for cross-compilation from Linux to Windows target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934683/how-do-i-configure-qt-for-cross-compilation-from-linux-to-windows-target)

or you can compile it on your Linux Distribution maybe inside the VM-ware .

also good read if you need more : https://forum.qt.io/topic/16018/how-to-compile-a-qt-application-targeting-for-linux-from-a-windows-machine/15

Source : Internet.