# Build SIP and PyGlobalShortcut for Windows

Tags: qt, python-2.7, mingw, cross-compiling, mxe

I am writing a Python2.7/PyQt4 programm under Ubuntu, but the application will be deployed on a Windows platform. One of the functions is that the application should capture several keystrokes (e.g. "Alt+A") even if it is not in focus/minimized. I use [PyGlobalShortcut](https://github.com/Asvel/pygs) for this purpose, which is a Python/SIP wrapper around [libxqt](https://bitbucket.org/libqxt/libqxt/wiki/Home). Following the manual, I installed Qt4 + [SIP](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/intro) and ran the `pip install PyGlobalShortcut` command, which automatically compiled and installed the libqxt library and the Python wrapper. This worked flawlessly.

#### Building natively under Windows

However, I hit the wall trying to install PyGlobalShortcut under Windows. The binary distribution for the package is obsolete, meaning I have to compile it myself. I had to install Qt4 + MinGW and tweak `$PATH`, which was not a problem. Next step is to get SIP, which is unfortunately not provided in a binary form for Py2.7. I got the source code of SIP, but was not able to build it:

```
sip-4.17 $ python configure.py --platform win32-g++
sip-4.17 $ make
```

`make` calls for `mingw32-make` which **immediately returns with an error that `MSVCR80.dll` could not be found**. I googled a bit and it seems that it is a component of MS Visual Studio or something like that, but *what does it has to do with MinGW*? I was not able to find any kind of official web site that provides this dll or explains how to get it.

#### Cross-compiling under Linux

I also thought that may be I could cross-compile PyGlobalShortcut on Linux machine using [MXE](http://mxe.cc/). I did not manage to do this as well.
I used [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934683/how-do-i-configure-qt-for-cross-compilation-from-linux-to-windows-target/13211922#13211922) as a guidance. I've got MXE, cross-compiled Qt4 and checked with `wine` that it works. Then I included `<mxe>/usr/bin` and `<mxe>/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt/bin` into `$PATH` and tried to cross-compile SIP for windows. It failed miserably because Makefile called for native linux `g++` and not for c++ compiler of `MXE`:

```
sip-4.17 $ python configure.py --platform win32-g++
sip-4.17 $ make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ximeg/dev/sip-4.17/sipgen'
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o main.o main.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o transform.o transform.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o gencode.o gencode.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o extracts.o extracts.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o export.o export.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o heap.o heap.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o parser.o parser.c
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o lexer.o lexer.c
g++ -mthreads -Wl,-enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -Wl,-subsystem,console -Wl,-s -o sip main.o transform.o gencode.o extracts.o export.o heap.o parser.o lexer.o 
main.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [sip] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ximeg/dev/sip-4.17/sipgen'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So I symlinked compilers and linker under `<mxe>/usr/bin`, i.e. `i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++` to `g++` etc. This helped, but now `g++` requires Python libraries and headers. It looks for them under `/usr/include/python2.7` - but they are compiled for linux and therefore cannot be linked to windows binaries.

```
sip-4.17 $ make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ximeg/dev/sip-4.17/sipgen'
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -o main.o main.c
...
g++ -mthreads -Wl,-enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -Wl,-subsystem,console -Wl,-s -o sip main.o transform.o gencode.o extracts.o export.o heap.o parser.o lexer.o 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ximeg/dev/sip-4.17/sipgen'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ximeg/dev/sip-4.17/siplib'
gcc -c -O2 -w -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -o siplib.o siplib.c
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from siplib.c:20:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:78:3: error: #error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
 # error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,
                 from siplib.c:20:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:78:3: error: #error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
 # error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/pymath.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:77,
                 from siplib.c:20:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:78:3: error: #error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
 # error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
   ^
siplib.c: In function 'wrapInstance':
siplib.c:1342:27: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'addr'
     unsigned PY_LONG_LONG addr;
                           ^
siplib.c:1342:27: error: 'addr' undeclared (first use in this function)
siplib.c:1342:27: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
siplib.c: In function 'parsePass1':
siplib.c:4488:9: error: expected ';' before 'case'
         case 'c':
         ^
siplib.c:4526:9: error: expected ';' before 'case'
         case 'b':
         ^
make[1]: *** [siplib.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ximeg/dev/sip-4.17/siplib'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems that I need a Windows build of Python to compile this stuff, placed under `<mxe root>`, but...  **Come on, now it's getting way too complicated**. I'm pretty sure that *I am missing something simple here*. Unfortunately I don't have much experience in compiling for Windows and would appreciate any help.

#### Other options for shortcuts?

I do not mind to rewrite my Python program and use any other cross-platform library to catch global shorcuts, but I did not found any other except PyGlobalShortcut.