# Linux --> Windows CrossCompilation Error with QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling

I want to do a cross compilation on Linux for a Windows use.
I have download the compiler MinGW for C++ on my VM, I tried to set it up as a Kit, and here's the error I have :

`Error: The compiler "MinGW (C++, ×86 64bit at /usr/bin/×86_64-w64-mingw32-g++)" (x86-windows-msys-pe-64bit) cannot produce code for the Qt version "Qt 6.4.1 GCC 64bit" (x86-linux-generic-elf-64bit).`

Do I have to download an other version of MinGW? Which one then?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you add more information how you're compiling? Which tool gives you those errors?

Comment: You need to use cmake or qmake compiled for crosscompilation

Comment: I am using QT Creator on Ubuntu, I want to compile on the Qt 6.4.1 GCC 64 bit. I have download the compilator MinGW(C++, x86 64 bit). The error appears when I click on "manage Kits" on the left of the kit I have created. (There's a red flag with a ! in it.) I use CMak 3.24.2 (Qt)

Comment: to use cmake the project must be `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: What do you mean by it must be CMakeLists.txt ? Can you precise please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934683/how-do-i-configure-qt-for-cross-compilation-from-linux-to-windows-target

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-manual.html, there is about cross-compiling

Comment: You should at least start with mingw64 instead of w32....

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue on Arch. I think this "warning" is a bug. I just ignore that fact, and try build app. I wasn't get any errors, even was try to open output .exe in Windows and don't notice any issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).